# iOS Firebase -How to remove children with same key from different nodes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a ref named Following. Under that ref there are 2 different userIds who are following the same user. If the user they are both following wants to delete their account I want to delete them from the Following node. Multi location update doesn't seem correct to achieve this.

How can it be done?

[image]

User kk8qFOIw... is the user who is deleting their account. Once deleted their keys should be removed from the other user's nodes.

Comment: Please edit the question with your multi location update that didn't work the way you expected.  A correct one should.

Comment: @DougStevenson hey thanks for the advice. i actually didn't attempt it because I said to myself if someone has thousands of followers how will a multi location update work? I know how to do it at several different locations but not at hundreds or possibly more.

Comment: You will have to write code to manage all these locations.  It will not just happen automatically or by wildcard.

Comment: The only thing I came up with was to loop through all the users and delete from there. The guy who answered below did the same thing. A loop for a couple of users would be fine but for a ton it doesn’t seem efficient. Is that my only choice?

Comment: You could always flip the logic; instead of users having child nodes of who they are following, the user that's being followed could have child nodes of who is following them. When that user is deleted, their child node of who is following them is deleted as well. One call does it all. If you go that route, when a user logs in they simply query the node that contains users they could be following for their own uid.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the suggestion. If the user who is being followed has child nodes of who’s following them, then how would the followers know who they’re following? Everything is under that followed user’s node

Comment: That was the second part of my suggestion *If you go that route, when a user logs in they simply query the node that contains users they could be following for their own uid*. I don't know your structure but I would have a node (call it /who_is_following_me) that has user_id's as children and their child nodes are a list of uid's that are following them.  When a user logs in, query that node for their uid: true. That will return all of the uid's they are following. If a user gets deleted, delete their node under /who_is_following_me. This eliminates iterating and even multi-path updates.

Comment: @Jay great suggestion, I’ll try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it :

First get all the nodes where your id = 1 , then run a multipath update and set them to empty.

```
 let userId = "yourUserId"
    self.ref.child("following").queryOrdered(byChild: userId).queryEqual(toValue: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snasphot) in
        guard let value = snasphot.value as? [String : Any] else {return}


        var multipathUpdate = [String:Any]()
        value.keys.forEach({ (key) in
            multipathUpdate["following/"+key+"/"+userId] = [:]
        })
        self.ref.updateChildValues(multipathUpdate, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

        })
    }
```

Comment: It works but it leads to another problem. Because of the query it gives a warning: Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "kK8qF0IwqRg9fiHBQeCjChrxYgg2" at /following to your security rules for better performance. I can't add userId's as an indexOn

Comment: There is also another problem. I initially was going to do it another where I looped through all the children and deleted id but then I realized if someone has thousands of followers that's a lot of users to loop through. Your plan works but it's doing the same thing, its looping through everyone. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: then this can be handled from the cloud functions or you can make changes to the database structure

Comment: Can you provide a link on how to do it using cloud functions?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started 
see this link, in step 4 you can write the code to make changes in the database.

Comment: This will generate an http endpoint which you can call from client side and get the job done, but you will have to write server side code in the cloud function.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your answer works. Even though the loop is a drawback, I have to admit it does work.

Comment: yup you are write that loop is a drawback , but with firebase sometimes there is no other solution i guess.