# Firebase dynamic links builder API for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to use firebase cloud functions to build my dynamic link rather than use an android client API

```
    @VisibleForTesting
    static Uri buildDeepLink(@NonNull final Uri deepLink, int minVersion) {
        String uriPrefix = "https://url.page.link";

        DynamicLink.Builder builder = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .createDynamicLink()
                .setDomainUriPrefix(uriPrefix)
                .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder()
                        .setMinimumVersion(minVersion)
                        .build())
                .setLink(deepLink);

        final DynamicLink link = builder.buildDynamicLink();
        // Return the dynamic link as a URI
        return link.getUri();
    }
```

The above code is for android client, is there a similar code for cloud functions environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Dynamic Links currently has [SDKs for creating links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701778/ios-firebase-how-to-remove-children-with-same-key-from-different-nodes) for iOS, Android, Unity, and C++. It also has a REST API for other platforms. Since you're not using Android or iOS, you'll have to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest).

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling lazy, you can also use this small package instead of the REST API:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-dynamic-links