# How to delete a key from various locations at once firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"Questions" : {
"-LnZ3OzV1iKpYIGZ8xlV" : {
    "Answer_Key" : [ "test16b" ],
    "AnsweredBy" : {
        "WoKKRAsyWAccTS30DZseOe7VxBV2" : [ "test16a" ]
        "V2RAsyWAWoKKeOe7VxBccTS30DZs" : [ "test16b" ]
    },
    "Question_And_Options" : [ "test16", "test16a", "test16b" ]
},
}



"users":{
"WoKKRAsyWAccTS30DZseOe7VxBV2": {
"AnsweredQuestions" : [ "-Ln0gR4ffid1kMWo4Xbx" ],
"Questions" : {
"-LnZ3OzV1iKpYIGZ8xlV","Ln0gR4ffid1kMWo4Xbx" : {
 "Question" : [ "Sample Test Question 1", "Sample Test Answer 1","Sample Test Answer 2", "Sample Test Answer 3", "Sample Test Answer 4", "Sample Test Answer 5", "Sample Test Answer 6" ]
}
},
"email" : "test25@gmail.com",
"name" : "test25"
}
"V2RAsyWAWoKKeOe7VxBccTS30DZs": {
    "AnsweredQuestions" : [ "-Ln0gR4ffid1kMWo4Xbx" ],
    "Questions" : {
        "-LnZ3OzV1iKpYIGZ8xlV","Ln0gR4ffid1kMWo4Xbx" : {
            "Question" : [ "Sample Test Question 1", "Sample Test Answer 1", "Sample Test Answer 2", "Sample Test Answer 3", "Sample Test Answer 4", "Sample Test Answer 5", "Sample Test Answer 6" ]
        }
    },
    "email" : "test25@gmail.com",
    "name" : "test25"
}
}
```

I'm trying to delete a key from multiple places in firebase. For example if a questions(having a unique key) is deleted from "Questions", I want to delete it form users/uid/AnsweredQuestions. But the problem is a particular question can be answered by many users, so how to delete the unique key of the question from the entire firebase?[image: Structure of database for user test 25]
[image: Structure of database for user test 26]

I want to delete the "-LnZ3OzV1iKpYIGZ8xlV" which is answered by both test 25 and test 26.

This is what i've done so far. I'm fetching the users and for each user I'm checking for that particular question_key.

```
func getUsers(refe: String, completion: @escaping (([String]) -> ())){
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "URL")
    ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap) in

        let enumerator = snap.children
        var newArray = [String]()
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            newArray.append(rest.key)
        }
        completion(newArray)
}
}

 let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "URL")
self.getUsers(refe: reference!) { (arr) in
    for key in arr{
        ref.child("users/\(key)/AnsweredQuestions").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value as? String{
                if value == self.reference!{
                print("\(key) & \(value) & \(self.reference!)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm able to fetch the users who have the question_key in their answeredQuestion.

Output:

```
5U3a3A64ywYG1LuGfBedCr46Idz2 & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU
WXmDXuHPDXhnom4llOiPiveFzfH3 & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU
rJRrNBH19wShlaDBbEb0kPqoRVd2 & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU
tYUuLWuybteaTOiRwCd2TbWWmp22 & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU & -LndcF0cUq2diC7fM8JU
```

Now how do I delete these ids?

Comment: To delete a node, you need to know the full path to that node. So you'll first need to query the database to find the answers that have a link to the question. Then you'll want to do a multi-location update to delete all of those nodes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701778/ios-firebase-how-to-remove-children-with-same-key-from-different-nodes. If you're having a hard time implement this solution for your own use-case, edit your question to show what you have tried already.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've edited the question and added some code of what i'm trying to do.